# Difference between eigenbasis and basis for an eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my class, the teachers keep asking for either the eigenbasis or the basis for the eigenspace. They sound the same, but is there a difference between eigenbasis of a matrix and basis for an eigenspace?

To solve the eigenbasis of a matrix given eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 ... \lambda_n$
you would solve the vector $\vec{v}$ for $(A - \lambda I | 0)$.

However I'm unsure how to find the basis of an eigenspace. Are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

An eigenbasis is a basis for the *whole* space. If you have a set of sufficiently many basis vectors for sufficiently many eigenspaces, then that's an eigenbasis, however an eigenbasis does not always exist in general (whereas a basis for the eigenspace *does* always exist in general). Specifically, if you have $n$ eigenvalues (with multiplicity) of an $n\times n$ matrix (over an algebraically closed field...) *and* every eigenvalue - say, with multiplicity $k$ - has $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to that value (the *geometric multiplicity* is $k$) then there are enough eigenvectors to span the whole space.

A matrix is *diagonalisable* (essentially) if an eigenbasis exists. If not, you need to resort to the more general [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and [generalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) eigenvectors/eigenbases.

Comment: "an eigenbasis is a basis for the whole space", meaning it's a basis for R^n?

Comment: Assuming that's the vector space you are working in.   It's generalizable to any vector space though